# Biased Distribution described in "Think Stats"

Tags: mathematical-statistics

In the Chapter 3 of [Think Stats by Allen Downey](http://greenteapress.com/wp/think-stats-2e/) book. The following is the [excerpt from the book](http://greenteapress.com/thinkstats2/html/thinkstats2004.html#sec33):

> First, I compute the distribution as observed by students, where the
>   probability associated with each class size is “biased” by the number
>   of students in the class.
>
> ```
> def BiasPmf(pmf, label):
>   new_pmf = pmf.Copy(label=label)
>
>   for x, p in pmf.Items():
>     new_pmf.Mult(x, x)
>
>   new_pmf.Normalize()
>   return new_pmf
> ```
>
> For each class size, x, we multiply the probability by x, the number
>   of students who observe that class size. The result is a new Pmf that
>   represents the biased distribution.

1. What is the meaning of the bias here?
2. Is the author skewing the value by a certain factor and thus, creating an artificial "bias"?

If there's a better forum to discuss questions regarding the book material - please let us know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This exercise is illustrating that the 'average class size' as calculated by the Dean is not the same as the average class size as experienced by a student.  The difference can be viewed this way: the Dean's average is the expected class size when picking a **class** at random, while the student's average is the expected class size when picking a **student** at random and asking the size of that student's class. To create a student-centric distribution of class sizes, you need to replicate each class size `x` as many times as the number of students in the class (again, `x`). In other words:

```
for x, p in pmf.Items():
    new_pmf.Mult(x, x)
```

This is the sense in which we are 'biasing' class sizes: to give a student's-eye view of the class distribution. It's a legitimate approach, not anything artificial. Both versions of the average class size are correctly calculated; the difference is in the sampling scheme.

(Note this exercise is a little muddled: what if a student takes more than one class? The code for creating the biased distribution is making the simplifying assumption that each student takes just one class.)

Comment: Thank you. I am having a hard time internalizing this though. Why is there a multiplication happening?

Comment: @neowulf33  Example: if a college had just two classes, one with 2 students and one with 3 students, the Dean's data set would be {2, 3}, one value per class. But in the student's view the data set would be {2, 2, 3, 3, 3}, one value per student, i.e., 2 is replicated twice, 3 is replicated thrice.  Say the Dean's pmf is p(x). The software achieves replication by replacing each p(x) by x * p(x), and then renormalizes the result. [ Recall Mult(x, c) means 'multiply the probability for value x by the factor c'.]  There are other ways to compute the student pmf, e.g. just create a new data set.